# переход со swift 1.2 в swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

Друзья, подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего возникает и как устранить следующую ошибку. Есть код, работающий на swift 1.2 в Xcode 6. При попытке запустить его в swift 2 в Xcode 7 возникает ошибка. Вот сам код - берем введенные значения, вызываем функцию сompare сравнения с заданными, которая возвращает true или false

```
var passwd=textfield.text
var login=loginfield.text
let ver = compare(login, b:passwd)
    if ver == true {
        label.text="True"
    }
    else {
        label.text="False"
    }
}
```

В swift 2 вылазит ошибка на строке:

```
let ver = compare(login, b:passwd)
 "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

Почему это и куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значение, которое выходит из текстового поля может быть пустым, и соответственно содержать nil. Поэтому компилятор обозначает это значение как optional (String?).

Предполагаю, что Ваша функция compare принимает в качестве параметра "String", а вы подаёте туда тип "String?"

Чтобы исправить ошибку нужно либо сказать компилятору, чтобы в случае если поля содержат nil, заменить их на пустую строку:

```
var passwd=textfield.text ?? ""
var login=loginfield.text ?? ""
```

Либо изменить Вашу функцию, чтобы она в качестве параметра принимала optional "String?"

Comment: Да, вы совершенно правы. Изменил функцию на "String?", все заработало. Еще работал вариант указать var passwd=textfield.text!
var login=loginfield.text!, но это как я понимаю, менее правильный путь?

Comment: Oleg, при таком подходе может быть ошибка "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value", если поля пустые.